# Got a weird trans-purple cone part as extra in 71043-1 Hogwarts Castle

Tags: part-identification

I bought a [71043-1](https://brickset.com/sets/71043-1/Hogwarts-Castle) and one of the extra parts is this trans-purple "cone" with the smaller through-hole, which couldn't identify since there is no element number, only the mould number which is 05-B01.

Here's a picture, (normal stud as a comparison) - please help me identify or give an element number for this!

[image: 1]

Answer (score 23):

It looks like a "short shot" of [Minifigure, Utensil Bottle, Erlenmeyer Flask with Trans-Purple Fluid Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=93549pb02&idColor=12#T=C&C=12) (pictured below) which is included in the set. I would even say it lacks the Trans-clear "coating" around Trans-Purple piece of the combined element.

[image]

Short shot - is a term used in LEGO community to describe an uncommon occurrence of plastic element production, where element is produced with insufficient amount of plastic. There could be various reasons: temperature is too low, lack of plastic supply and other errors during production.

Comment: Yeah, I was supposed to say the same. This is must be the origin of the part and how it ended in the same bag as the flask. Somekind of premold and inner piece for the flask since both even have the center hole in them, that would also explain why it has a mould number but no element number. Pretty cool since this must be crazy rare because in all of my 20 years of legos have I ever seen such occur on my sets!

Comment: I wonder if that's the entire inner purple part prior to the clear plastic jacket being molded around it.

Comment: I wonder how much money an error piece like that would be worth?

Comment: Same here, market for these kind of occurrences are probably very slim so the pricing most likely is what the seller asks for so in other words priceless, only this time quite literally :)